# PWAIT_ALL_COMPONENTS_INITIALIZED and WAIT_XTP_HOST_WAIT high average ms per wait

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, sp-blitz

I ran `exec sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1, @OutputType = 'Top10'` and got the below output. Everything seems good except I dont know what `PWAIT_ALL_COMPONENTS_INITIALIZED` or `WAIT_XTP_HOST_WAIT` is and it seems high.  Are those concerning and what are they?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, these are not concerning, and I base that on the research Paul Randal has already done.

#### `PWAIT_ALL_COMPONENTS_INITIALIZED` ([Waits Library](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/pwait_all_components_initialized/))

This is a wait you'll see during SQL Server startup. Not much you can do about it even if you do believe it is causing other problems (and I seriously doubt that it is). Paul completely [filters this out as a benign wait in all of his waits analysis](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/).

#### `WAIT_XTP_HOST_WAIT` ([Waits Library](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/wait_xtp_host_wait/))

Paul also filters out `WAIT_XTP_HOST_WAIT` in all of his waits analysis because it is a non-actionable wait involved with regular Memory-Optimized table mechanics.

I would seriously adopt [Paul's set of filters](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/) in your regular waits analysis toolkit so you're only looking at waits that (a) are a problem and (b) you can do anything about.